# what is "binds_to_weak" and "weak_defines" flag signify in otool output?

Tags: ios, otool

after using the below command i am getting the two flags as "binds_to_weak" and "weak_defines". what is their significance?

$ otool -hv

(architecture armv7):
Mach header
     magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
  MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00     EXECUTE    38       4292   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL WEAK_DEFINES BINDS_TO_WEAK PIE

Answer (score 0):

MH_WEAK_DEFINES means that an executable has a *weak symbol*. Weak symbols are a linker trick to avoid linking in supporting code which isn't used. For example, the compiler does its analysis and determines that the application is integer only and tells the linker to not link in floating point support code. From the [Oracle® Solaris 11.4 Linkers and Libraries Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E36783/index.html) (which is not talking about Mach-O):

> Historically, weak symbols have been used to circumvent interposition,
>   or test for optional functionality. However, experience has shown that
>   weak symbols are fragile and unreliable in modern programming
>   environments, and their use is discouraged.

This is explained better in Chapter 6 of John Levine's *Linkers and Loaders*.